# How to read all array elements in mongodb in pipeline?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, object, pipeline, metabase

I'm using mongodb compass reading a json file. As a result of a pipeline that I need, I had an array composed of many objects.

Ps:

- I can't use python script because I need pipeline dealing with metabase.
- I want a function or an idea of transforming those objects of the array to independent objects that I can read it in metabase.
- I used `$arrayElemAt` just to verify the existence of the object

This is my pipeline that I used

```
[
 {$group: {"_id":"$Marque","doc":{"$push":"$$ROOT"}}}, 

 {$replaceRoot: {
  newRoot: {'$arrayElemAt': ['$doc',0] }

}}]
```

the output that I had

```
_id:"PEUGEOT"
doc:Array
0:Object
1:Object
2:Object
```

in which Object 0 is

```
0:Object
_id:"5f05b00d176114743b25ee72"
Boite_de_Vitesse:"Manuelle"
Carburant:"Essence"
Carrosserie:"Berline"
Couleur:"NOIR"
Date_Annonce:2020-07-07T00:00:00.000+00:00
Date_Scraping:2020-07-08T12:37:49.337+00:00
Description:"2016 peugeot 208 1 ère main 34 900 dt négociable 23/02/2016 tu187 1.2l..."
Etat:"excellent"
Kilometrage:83000
Marque:"PEUGEOT"
Mise_en_circulation:2016-05-01T00:00:00.000+00:00
Modele:"208"
Prix:34900
Puissance_Fiscale:5
Source:"Auto-plus"
Titre:"Tap929-Peugeot 208 1 Ère Main"
URL_Annonce:"https://www.auto-plus.tn/voitures-d-occasion/a_vendre/tap929-peugeot-2..."
Vendeur:"Tunisie Auto Prix"
Ville:"Ben Arous"
Longitude:10.177
Latitude:36.676
```

the output expected is like this :

```
  _id:"5f05b049176114743b25eed2"
Boite_de_Vitesse:"Automatique"
Carburant:"Essence"
Carrosserie:"SUV"
Couleur:"NOIR"
Date_Annonce:2020-07-04T00:00:00.000+00:00
Date_Scraping:2020-07-08T12:38:49.806+00:00
Description:"2009 bmw x6 bva toit ouvrant xdrive 35i 139 000 dt négociable 29/04/20..."
Etat:"excellent"
Kilometrage:59000
Marque:"BMW"
Mise_en_circulation:2009-05-01T00:00:00.000+00:00
Modele:"X6"
Prix:139000
Puissance_Fiscale:22
Source:"Auto-plus"
Titre:"2009 Bmw X6 Bva Toit Ouvrant Xdrive 35I"
URL_Annonce:"https://www.auto-plus.tn/voitures-d-occasion/a_vendre/2009-bmw-x6-bva-..."
Vendeur:"Tunisie Auto Prix"
Ville:"Ben Arous"
Longitude:10.177
Latitude:36.676
```

and the other object out of the array.
Like the screenshot below [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gj9Da.png)
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you add an input example and expected output?. And please, use text instead of images.

Comment: Thank you @J.F. i edited it now  if you can take a look